# Print first N prime numbers in Common Lisp

Tags: printing, numbers, lisp, primes, clisp

I am making a Common Lisp function to print the first N prime numbers. So far I've managed to write this code:

```
;globals 
(setf isprime 1) ;if 1 then its a prime, 0 if not.
(setf from 1)    ;start from 1
(setf count 0)   ;should act as counter to check if we have already 
                 ;    N primes printed

;function so far.
(defun prime-numbers (to)
  (if (> count to) nil(progn
      (is-prime from from)
      (if (= isprime 1) (print from)(setf count (+ count 1)))
      (setf isprime 1)
      (setf from (+ from 1))
      (prime-numbers to)))
  (if (>= count to)(setf count 0) (setf from 1)))  

;code to check if a number is prime    
(defun is-prime(num val)
  (if (< num 3) nil 
    (progn
      (if (= (mod val (- num 1)) 0) (setf isprime 0))
      (is-prime (- num 1) val))))
```

My problem is, it does not print N primes correctly.
If I call `>(prime-numbers 10)`,
results are:
`1 
2 
3 
5 
7 
11 
13 
17 
19 
1`, 
i.e. it printed only 9 primes correctly.

but then if i call `>(prime-numbers 2)`
the results are: `1 
2 
3 
5 
7 
1`

what am I doing wrong here?? this is my first time to code in LISP.

UPDATE:

```
  (defparameter from 1)
  (defparameter count 0)

  (defun prime-numbers (to)
     (if (> count to)nil
         (progn
            (when (is-prime from) 
                (print from)
                (setf count (+ count 1)))
            (setf from (+ from 1))
            (prime-numbers to)))
     (when (>= count to)
         (setf count 0) 
         (setf from 1)))  

  (defun is-prime (n)
    (cond ((= 2 n) t)
     ((= 3 n) t)
     ((evenp n) nil)
     (t 
       (loop for i from 3 to (isqrt n) by 2
             never (zerop (mod n i))))))
```

works fine. but outputs a NIL at the end.

Comment: Please fix code formatting and remove the backticks in front of `defun`s

Comment: CLISP is an implementation of the programming language "Common Lisp".

Comment: I've re-indented your first code and didn't touch the second. You have some improper indentation there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, there's no need to use globals here, at all.

Use true/false return values. That would allow your `is-prime` function to be something like:

```
(defun is-prime (n)
  (cond ((= 2 n) t) ;; Hard-code "2 is a prime"
        ((= 3 n) t) ;; Hard-code "3 is a prime"
        ((evenp n) nil) ;; If we're looking at an even now, it's not a prime
        (t ;; If it is divisible by an odd number below its square root, it's not prime
           (loop for i from 3 to (isqrt n) by 2
                 never (zerop (mod n i))))))
```

That way, the function is not relying on any external state and there's nothing that can confuse anything.

Second, the last `1` you see is (probably) the return value from the function.

To check that, try:
    (progn (prime-numbers 10) nil)

Third, re-write your `prime-numbers` function to not use global variables.

Fourth, never create global variables with [`setf`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_setf_.htm) or [`setq`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_setq.htm), use either [`defvar` or `defparameter`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defpar.htm). It's also (mostly, but some disagree) good style to use `*earmuffs*` on your global (really, "special") variables.

Comment: you can use `always` in your `loop` instead of `return-from`.

Comment: @sds True. It's been a few years since I wrote loops in anger and `return-from` was within trivial reach.

Comment: @sds Rewritten using `never`.

Comment: thank you for this!. but I still don't have the required outputs. besides the globals. what could be wrong with my prime-numbers?

Comment: @binaryjc I actually think using globals is causing your problem. Using global state for communicating between functions is close to the best way of making your code not work there is.

Comment: @binaryjc The main problem now is the IFs in your function. IF requres that each branch contains just one form, while you try to evaluate two forms when the test is true. Try changing the last two IFs to WHEN or add a PROGN. This is more clear when the code is properly formatted.

Comment: change the IFs to WHEN worked. but a NIL is outputed at the END. is it because of the condition, that if it already printed N primes?

Comment: @binyryjc Nil is the return value of the function. When the desired number of primes is found, count is reset in the last `when`, and as the recursion unwinds the test in that `when` form fails and `nil` is returned. For a rewrite of the prime-numbers: See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Vatines answer:

A possible rewrite of the `prime-numbers` function, using the same algoritm but avoiding globals is

```
(defun prime-numbers (num &optional (from 2))
   (cond ((<= num 0) nil)
         ((is-prime from) (cons from (prime-numbers (1- num) (1+ from))))
         (t (prime-numbers num (1+ from)))))
```

This function also returns the primes instead of printing them.

The problem with this recursive solution is it consumes stack for each prime found/tested.  Thus stack space may be exhausted for large values of num.

A non-recursive variant is

```
(defun prime-numbers (num &optional (start 2))
   (loop for n upfrom start
         when (is-prime n)
         sum 1 into count
         and collect n
         until (>= count num)))
```